# Help understand validates_each Rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
     validates_each :name, :email do |model, attr, value|
             if value =~ /groucho|harpo|chico/i 
                   model.errors.add(attr, "You can't be serious, #{value}")
              end 
     end
end
```

Confused as to how this works.

Is :name, email the items it will loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:name` and `:email` are the attributes that will be validates using this block.

So each time a User is validated, the block will be called once with `attr = :name` and once with `attr = :email` (and each time `value` will hold the value of that attribute).